# Erlang OTP release compiles with HiPE?

Tags: erlang, hipe

After reading this question [Is Erlang the C of the clustered computing world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206313/is-erlang-the-c-of-the-clustered-computing-world) , I am wondering the official Erlang OTP compiles with HiPE?

In other words, when I compile my `.erl` source with the OTP release R13 (as example), does it produce "object code" BEAM?

Looking at http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/ , it does not appear that a standalone HiPE compiler is maintained anymore.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207451/erlang-compilation-mixed-of-hipe-object-code-and-opcode

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207481/what-are-the-constraints-limitations-of-compiling-with-native

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default HiPE is not used to compile OTP. It is known, however, that OTP libraries can be successfully compiled using HiPE with usually some performance boost (though it depends on your application).

When you run a `erlc` on your `.erl` file it produces BEAM file, which is NOT compiled to native code with HiPE. To compile an `.erl` file to native code using HiPE just run `erlc +native file.erl`.

Standalone HiPE compiler is not maintained anymore, since it was included into core Erlang/OTP distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I think this depends on what options you passed to the configure script when you compiled the Erlang compiler. It certainly can include it but whether it does by default or not is another issue.